# read -e in a sub script

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection

Let's imagine that I have `script1.sh` and `script2.sh` with the following sources:

Script 1:

```
#!/bin/bash
# script 1
echo "Doing some stuff..."
bash script2.sh
echo "Done"
```

And Script 2:

```
#!/bin/bash
# script 2
printf "\r  [ \033[0;33m?\033[0m ] What is your name? "
read -e name
echo "$name"
```

And calling `bash script1.sh` works gracefully.

I'm trying to do something similar [here](https://github.com/caarlos0/dotfiles/compare/master...install?expand=1) and executing `wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/caarlos0/dotfiles/install/script/install | bash`, but when it executes the `script/bootstrap` script, it exits in the `read -e`.

I tried the `-i` flag to force interactive with no success.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought: You're running `bash` with a pipe to standard input.  And then you're asking it to read from standard input.  That won't work.

Use a named pipe instead?

ETA: Or maybe not …

```
mkfifo ~/tmp-pipe
wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/caarlos0/dotfiles/install/script/install > ~/tmp-pipe &
bash ~/tmp-pipe
rm ~/tmp-pipe
```

By this time, if you also want to make sure you're not trampling on some existing file, you might as well use a tempfile: There'll be less mess to deal with:

```
P=$( mktemp )
wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/caarlos0/dotfiles/install/script/install > $P &
bash $P
rm $P
```

Yeah.  I dunno.

Comment: Yeah, `wget`ing and executing in different commands seems to fix it... but I really want a one-liner... any ideas?

Comment: well, seems like `bash -c "$(wget -O -  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/caarlos0/dotfiles/install/script/install)"` works. Will set your answer as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The standard input of the bash process is the script that's being downloaded by wget. So the call to `read` reads a line from that script, or reads nothing if bash has already finished the script.

`wget -O - … | bash` may be a cute one-liner, but it is not a good idea. If the download breaks in the middle, bash will execute the part of the script that could be downloaded, and the error from wget may be hard to detect. It would be better to first download the file, then execute it:

```
wget https://…/install
bash install
rm install
```

To avoid explicitly creating a temporary file, you can use process substitution instead. This requires your interactive shell to support process substitution: it must be bash, ksh93 or zsh. This suffers from the same downside as the pipe the script will be executed even if the download is interrupted, but it doesn't grab standard input, which remains the terminal.

```
bash <(wget -O - …)
```

If you want your script to support the `wget -O - … | bash` pipe method, then you can make the script read from the terminal, by putting `exec </dev/tty`. However, this is a bad idea which will cause many users to curse you, because it makes it impossible to automate the running of the script by simply feeding it responses on its standard input — instead one would have to use a tool like `expect` to run the script in a terminal even for automated use.

The `-i` option is irrelevant: bash isn't running interactively because it's running a script, and standard input isn't a terminal because it's redirected from a pipe. Turning on the `-i` option makes bash pretend it's being used interactively even though it's being passed a script on its standard input; that doesn't change the fact that standard input isn't the terminal.

By the way, this has nothing to do with the fact that the script is split in two. You'd see exactly the same things if the code from script 2 was in the main script.

Answer (score 0):

Others have mentioned that your standard input is being replaced by your streamed script. This is a common problem, but is easily solved:

```
bash 3<&0 <<\SCRIPT          #ref stdin in fd 3, replace stdin w/ SCRIPT
    echo Doing some stuff... #do your stuff
    printf "\r  [ \033[0;33m?\033[0m ] What is your name? "
    read -e name <&3         #read from original stdin
    echo "$name"
    echo Done
SCRIPT
```

In the above sequence I use a heredoc to stand-in for your piped script. Because a pipe has not already replaced the above `bash`'s stdin with whatever it was before *(usually a terminal)* the above is just a *little* less complicated than your script will need to be. But I did want to demonstrate how it would work, and this is the most simple way.

When `bash` is invoked all of the processes it runs later will inherit all of its fds - unless you explicitly `>&-` close them. So if you just do a simple redirection at invocation time, that redirection will cascade to all children. By duping fd 0 to fd 3 above it makes it possible to later `read <&3` that same fd without having to do anything annoying like `</dev/tty` - though the latter thing can be a good idea in the case that you have a good reason to interact w/ a user at a keyboard as opposed to what that user might pipe at you.

Anyway, the stdout will still go to the same place - so all of the `echo/printf` stuff will print to whatever out stream it would have been otherwise, but `bash` will take `stdin` from the streamed-in script and any other references to it will need to be explicit.

With your pipe you'll need one more layer though:

```
{ wget ... | bash; } 3<&0
```

That will work in much the same way. To do it so you don't have to explicitly reference the `<&3` stream for the `read` *(or any other command)*:

```
{   {   echo "script$$(){"
        wget ...
        printf "\n} <&3; script$$\n"
} |     bash
} 3<&0
```

In that way you actually define a function which contains your whole piped in script, and explicitly redirect your saved stdin to the function's stdin once you have read the whole thing in, *then* you call it. So all commands within will treat the `<&3` as your stdin and you don't have to alter its contents in any way to reference it, but you can still read the whole thing in over standard input.